# Bond vs Software_Watchdog? [ROS2]

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From what I can gather, [bond](http://wiki.ros.org/bond) ([ros2 implementation](https://github.com/ros/bond_core/tree/ros2)) and the Safety Working Group's [software_watchdog](https://github.com/ros-safety/software_watchdogs) package have similar functionality, in that they allow nodes to "check in" on each other and ensure the nodes are operating as expected by publishing a heartbeat periodically.

I am wondering if someone more familiar with these packages could offer some insight on how they might be different or when you might want to use one vs. the other?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380104/bond-vs-software_watchdog?-%5Bros2%5D/) by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1567 on 2021-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Almost certainly software_watchdog. We use bond in Nav2 because we set that up before software_watchdog or the similar DDS capabilities were exposed in ROS2. I'd be happy to move over to software_watchdog if someone had some cycles to convert us over!

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-12**:\

> We use bond in Nav2 because we set that up before software_watchdog or the similar DDS capabilities were exposed in ROS2

to make it a bit more explicit: `software_watchdog` can make use of the liveness and heartbeat detection infrastructure supported by DDS. That was not available when `bond` was created (which is a ROS 1 package, and the ROS 2 version is an almost straight port).

I believe that's what @stevemacenski is implicitly referring to.

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-06-12**:
That helps clarify, thanks to both of you